# Confirmation pop up on login submit

Tags: 7, javascript

I have built a site using drupal 7.41. I have added the login form by adding this line in my page.tpl.php "print render($page['login_container']);".

When user click on the login button I want to show a popup with options "yes" and "no". only when the user choose "yes" he/she should be logged in. I need change the style of this pop up, that's why I cannot use jquery window.confirm function.

I went through drupal documentations and found about the function [confirm_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/confirm_form/6#comment-5934).
this is what I am trying to do, but not able to.

I created a hook menu and then called the confirm_form fucntion.
But I am not able to call this from the login submit button.

Comment: Drupal doesn't have that functionality, you could easily provide it using javascript though

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some simple Javascript. E.g. by the help of JQuery you could bind a click/submit function on the login-form, show a confirm-window ("Would you really like to log in?") and if this is confirmed, submit login-data (or not).

Such a function could(!) look similar to this:

```
$('#user-login-form').submit(function(){
 var r = confirm("Would you really like to login?");

 if (r == true) {
    return true; // submit form-data
 } else {
    return false; // stay on page
 }
});
```

Comment: i need to style the pop up.

Comment: Hmm, in such a case you could try out to implement JQuery-UI which offers an easy way of styling dialog's.